# OperationalError at /bandlist/, no such table: polls_band

Tags: python, django

I am severely confused by this error. I have made migrations as I have seen that has been a running solution with a lot of other problems similar to mine. Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: polls_band

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\mysite\polls\views.py", line 117, in bandlist
    print(query)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 226, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 900, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 890, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: polls_band
```

Following from this, here are my models, where I assume the issue is.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    usertype = models.IntegerField()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def is_standard(self):
        return self.groups.filter(name='Standard').exists()

    def is_bl(self):
        return self.groups.filter(name='Band Leader').exists()

    def is_bm(self):
        return self.groups.filter(name='Band Member').exists()

    def is_venue(self):
        return self.groups.filter(name='Venue').exists()


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    groupID = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField()

class Band(models.Model):
    bandname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)   
    description = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField('User')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bandname
```

With the views being:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from polls.forms import NormalSignUpForm, VenueSignUpForm, BLSignUpForm, BMSignUpForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import *
from polls.models import User
from django.http import Http404

user = get_user_model()
def bandlist(request):
    query = Band.objects.all()
    print(query)
    args =  {'query': query}
    return render(request, 'bandlist.html', args)

def bandview(request, band):
    try:
        query = Band.objects.get(id = band)
    except:
        raise Http404()
    return render(request, "band.html", {"band": query})
```

With the template looking like this:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Band List</h1>
{% for band in bands %}
{{ band.bandname }}
<h3><a href='/bandlist/{{band.id}}'>{{ band.bandname }}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

If anyone could provide any information on this that would be fantastic as I am completely baffled on why this could be the case. That would be massively helpful, thank you.

EDIT: More information.

manage.py showmigrations polls presents

```
(OnNote) C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\mysite>python manage.py showmigrations polls
polls
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20180411_1427
```

EDIT 2: Even more information

Here are the contents of the second migration.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.12 on 2018-04-11 10:27
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('polls', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='band',
            name='bandname',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=50),
        ),
    ]
```

EDIT 3: Information

Here is 001

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.12 on 2018-04-11 10:17
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone
import polls.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('usertype', models.IntegerField()),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', polls.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Band',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('bandname', models.CharField(max_length=16)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('picture', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
                ('members', models.ManyToManyField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BandMember',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('bandManager', models.BooleanField()),
                ('bandname', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Band')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Event',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('eventname', models.CharField(max_length=16)),
                ('datetime', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('cost', models.CharField(max_length=4)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('bandname', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Band')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Groups',
            fields=[
                ('groupID', models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('permissions', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Position',
            fields=[
                ('positionID', models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('post', models.CharField(max_length=500)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserProfile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('picture', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
                ('groupID', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Groups')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Venue',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('venuename', models.CharField(max_length=16)),
                ('address', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ('website', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='event',
            name='venuesID',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Venue'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='bandmember',
            name='positionID',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Position'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='bandmember',
            name='userID',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.UserProfile'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Django seems to think this is under the `polls` app.  Is that intentional? what name does the table have in the migration where it is created?

Comment: When you say that you ran migrations, did you run both `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: Please show the output of `manage.py showmigrations polls`, and any migrations files for the `polls` app.

Comment: Alasdair, (OnNote) C:\Users\Ethan\Envs\OnNote\mysite>python manage.py showmigrations polls
polls
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20180411_1427

Comment: Alan, it is underneath the polls app, I'm not sure what the second half of you question means, if you could expand further that would be helpful thank you

Comment: Ralf, Yes I did both of these, the error occurred whilst running the manage.py migrate.

Comment: It looks like you need to edit the contents of 0002_auto_20180411_1427 into your question.

Comment: Alan, I have now done this

Comment: Please show the `0001` migration as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your database and migrations are out of sync. The first migration should have created the `polls_band` table in the database, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Getting your database and migrations back in sync can be very difficult. If your project is under development and you don't have any important data in the db, the easiest thing to do would be:

1. drop the database (**you'll lose any data in it**)
2. delete the migration files in the polls app
3. re-run `./manage.py makemigrations polls` to make new migrations for the polls app
4. run the migrations with `./manage.py migrate`

If there is important data in the database, you might be able to get the database and migrations back in sync doing something like the following:

1. Delete the `0002` migration which you haven't applied yet
2. Manually remove the `migrations.CreateModel(name='Band')` operation from your `0001` migration.
3. Finally re-run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.